# Visual Studio 2017 Nuget pack exclude Project reference as another nuget reference, add assembly instead

Tags: nuget, visual-studio-2017, nuget-package

When we create a nuget package in visual studio 2017, it adds the project references as another nuget reference by default.
How can we disable that while creating package and instead:

- Chose a different package name
- include the dll of the project instead while creating the package

Answer (score 19):

The `PackageReference` can be marked with `PrivateAssets="All"` to ensure that it doesn't end up as a NuGet dependency of the consuming library when packed. Then the consuming library can use a custom target to add files to the built nuget package. A full example for the `csproj` file could look like this:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netstandard2.0</TargetFramework>
    <TargetsForTfmSpecificBuildOutput>$(TargetsForTfmSpecificBuildOutput);IncludeP2PAssets</TargetsForTfmSpecificBuildOutput>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\testprivatelib\testprivatelib.csproj" PrivateAssets="All" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <Target Name="IncludeP2PAssets">
    <ItemGroup>
      <BuildOutputInPackage Include="$(OutputPath)\testprivatelib.dll" />
    </ItemGroup>
  </Target>
</Project>
```

Where `testprivatelib.csproj` is a project that builds a DLL that you want to additionally include into the `.nupkg` file and not publish an extra NuGet package for that referenced project.

Specifying different NuGet packages is more difficult. It requires manually creating a `.nuspec` file using it to pack a NuGet package. You can see an example how this can be done at https://github.com/dasMulli/nuget-include-p2p-example/tree/master/LibA - the `LibA.csproj` is set up to use `LibA.nuspec` when `dotnet pack` is called.

Comment: Adding  PrivateAssets="All" to ProjectReference helped even though Visual Studio 2023 didn't show it is even an option.

Thanks!