# How to pack a referenced project into a nuget package?

Tags: .net-core, nuget, nuget-package

I have a C# solution which contains 3 projects; Application.Server, Application.Client, and Application.Common.  Both server and client have a project reference to common.

I want to pack server and client up so that they can be used by other teams in my organisation.  I have some automated build pipeline set up that do so, and they publish the nuget packages for server and client.  They do not package or publish common.  When I inspect the nuget packages, I can see that they reference the common package.

Is there a way that I can get them to build that project into them self?  Ideally I don't want to publish the common package as it's pretty specific to my application, and it doesn't really make sense that it's something that's independently consumable by other departments.  I also don't want to have to worry about wrangling extra nuget packages if I can help it (as in reality, Common is actually several projects).

Comment: Maybe you want to use the PrivateAssets="All" for your ProjectReference? It's very similar to this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46376256/visual-studio-2017-nuget-pack-exclude-project-reference-as-another-nuget-referen

Answer (score 14):

If your projects are "old style"/non-SDK/traditional csproj, **AND** if any project uses a NuGet package, if all those NuGet references are defined using `packages.config`, then use you can use `nuget.exe pack -IncludeReferencedProjects`. However, if any of your projects use `PackageReference` to define their package references (new, SDK-style projects can only use PackageReference), then `nuget.exe pack` will not correctly create NuGet dependencies for those packages. For SDK style multi-targeting projects, `nuget pack` will probably completely fail.

The only supported way to pack projects that use `PackageReference`, or any SDK style project, is to use NuGet's MSBuild pack target (either `dotnet pack` or `msbuild -t:pack`). However, [this does not have an equivalent to nuget.exe's `IncludeReferencedProjects`](https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/3891).

If your projects are SDK style, it really shouldn't be any more difficult to create and publish one package or many packages. Simply run `dotnet pack` on your solution, and every packable project gets packed (remember to mark any class library project you don't want to become a package as not packable). Then use your favourite scripting language to find and publish all nupkg files. For example (`Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Filter *.nupkg $SLN_DIR | ForEach-Object { & dotnet nuget push $_ }`, or copy/move all nupkgs to a single place (or use the appropriate setting to make NuGet create the packages there in the first place) and use `dotnet nuget push *.nupkg`.

The NuGet team recommends one package per assembly, and the tooling automatically creates NuGet dependencies for project references, so it all "just works" out of the box. To create a package with all the assemblies included, instead of NuGet dependencies, requires you to do a bunch of work.

Comment: "The NuGet team recommends one package per assembly" - do you have any links to that recommendations?

Comment: @JakubPawlinski: Please take a look on the "NuGet" in Microsoft Documentation, scroll down to the "Package targeting compatibility".

Comment: The script you mentioned seems promising, but I get `error: Source parameter was not specified.` It seems it's expecting `$_` to be followed with `-s`, but I'm not sure why. Any idea what's wrong?

Comment: @OfirD as per [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-nuget-push): Starting with NuGet 3.4.2, this is a mandatory parameter unless the NuGet config file specifies a DefaultPushSource value. For more information, see [Configuring NuGet behavior](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/configuring-nuget-behavior).

Answer (score -3):

Put the following into `./Directory.Build.targets`

```xml
<Project>
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetsForTfmSpecificBuildOutput>$(TargetsForTfmSpecificBuildOutput);IncludeP2POutput</TargetsForTfmSpecificBuildOutput>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <Target Name="IncludeP2POutput" DependsOnTargets="ResolveReferences">
    <ItemGroup>
      <BuildOutputInPackage Include="@(ReferenceCopyLocalPaths->WithMetadataValue('ReferenceSourceTarget', 'ProjectReference')->WithMetadataValue('PrivateAssets', 'all'))" />
    </ItemGroup>
  </Target>
</Project>
```

Then add `PrivateAssets="all"` to all `ProjectReference`'s you want to be packed into parent's package.

Here's how the recommendation works step-by-step:

1. Create or update `./Directory.Build.targets` file:
   In the root directory of your project or solution, create or update the `Directory.Build.targets` file. This file allows you to customize the build process across all projects in your solution.
2. Define a custom build target:
   Within the `./Directory.Build.targets` file, define a custom build target named `IncludeP2POutput`. This target will be executed during the build process and will determine which project references to include in the parent project's NuGet package.
3. Modify the `TargetsForTfmSpecificBuildOutput` property:
   The `TargetsForTfmSpecificBuildOutput` property is used by the .NET build system to determine which targets should be executed during the build process for a specific target framework. By adding `IncludeP2POutput` to this property, you're telling the build system to run the custom build target for each target framework of the parent project.
4. Add `PrivateAssets="all"` to relevant `ProjectReference` elements:
   In your parent project (the one that references other projects), locate the `ProjectReference` elements that you want to include in the NuGet package. Add the attribute `PrivateAssets="all"` to these `ProjectReference` elements. This attribute tells the build system to treat these references as private assets, meaning they won't be treated as dependencies by the consuming projects.
5. Custom build target logic:
   The custom build target `IncludeP2POutput` is triggered during the build process and runs after the `ResolveReferences` target (a built-in target). Inside the target, an `ItemGroup` is defined to select the project references with the specified metadata values (`ReferenceSourceTarget` set to `'ProjectReference'` and `PrivateAssets` set to `'all'`). These references are then added to the `BuildOutputInPackage` item group.

By following these steps, when you run `dotnet pack` on the parent project, the selected project references with `PrivateAssets="all"` will be included in the NuGet package of the parent project. Other projects consuming the parent project as a package will not see these references as dependencies, making them effectively hidden.

Please note that the behavior and capabilities of the .NET SDK and build system may evolve over time, so it's essential to refer to the official Microsoft documentation and release notes for the most up-to-date information on this topic.

Comment: -3 but not one reason describing why?

Comment: I think this doesn't include referenced project's content files, nor transitive package references.