# Prevent nuget from importing references as packages

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, nuget

I am trying to publish a nuget packed using dotnet pack along with all references dll´s. Hence I added a Content include node to include all the referenced dll's inside the pushed package.

```
<ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\MyDA\MyDA.csproj" />
    <ProjectReference Include="..\Interfaces\Interfaces.csproj" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Content Include="$(OutDir)\*.dll">
      <PackagePath>lib\$(TargetFramework)</PackagePath>
      <Pack>true</Pack>
    </Content>
  </ItemGroup>
```

The problem is when I import the nuget into a project it tries to get the references as packages from the feed which is what I trying to avoid by including the dll´s in the same package. Here is the error when importing the nuget.

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   NU1101  Unable to find package MyDA. No packages exist with this id in source(s): Microsoft Visual Studio Offline Packages, nuget.org, MyFeed   MySolution  C:\MySolution\MyDA\MyDA.csproj  1
```

Is there a way to prevent importing the references as packages from the Feed?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Build NuGet Package automatically including referenced dependencies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16173568/build-nuget-package-automatically-including-referenced-dependencies)

Comment: Hi @nilsK thanks your link directed me to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46376256/visual-studio-2017-nuget-pack-exclude-project-reference-as-another-nuget-referen which solved the problem

Comment: Great, have a nice weekend!